# Modular structure for behave tests

Tags: python, python-behave

Right now I have the following directory of test features:

```
Tests/
--BehaveTest1/
----BehaveTest1.feature
----steps/
------test_steps.py
--BehaveTest2/
----BehaveTest2.feature
----steps/
------test_steps.py
```

As the test steps for BehaveTest1 and BehaveTest2 are common, I'd like to implement a common module that could be called by both test cases when they need to. At the moment I have made a common/ directory inside the Tests/ folder and import it (inside the test_steps.py files for each test feature) by:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('../common')
import common
```

But I do not want to mess with the path so I was wondering if there are any better ways to do this with the structure of behave test features?

Comment: What is in that common module? Step definitions?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul functions used by step definitions. These are quite common between the behave tests for what I am doing.

Comment: Then you could define them in environment and they will be automatically pulled in on execution. Either or both in `envrionment.py` and in environmental control steps.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul but the environment.py file is inside the Behave tests folder. How will this be visible to all Behave tests?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The most flexible way to do this for me was to create a folder of my classes inside my steps folder:

```
features/test.feature
test_steps/
test_steps/classes
test_environment.py
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should throw in my two cents for anyone seeing this in the future: Although this may work, it's not considered best practice to place code being tested inside the directories containing test-related matter. Doing this is more likely to lead to problems in the future, such as duplicated code, or having the application that needs the definitions in "classes.py" fail to import it from such a strange place. In theory, it should be possible to leave the tests out of an installation/distribution and still have no trouble operating the software as intended.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to mess with `sys.path`, and this is not dependent on the version of Python you are using. This works just as well with Python 2.7 or Python 3.x.

Given the following file structure:

```
Tests/
├── BehaveTest1
│   ├── BehaveTest1.feature
│   └── steps
│       └── test_steps.py
├── BehaveTest2
│   ├── BehaveTest2.feature
│   └── steps
│       └── test_steps.py
├── common.py
├── __init__.py
```

**The presence of `__init__.py` in the `Tests` directory is key.** It is an empty file, but without it, Python will fail to load the module because `Tests` won't be considered to be a package.

I can have `test_steps.py` in both directories just do:

```
import Tests.common
```

And the `Tests/common.py` file contains:

```
from behave import when, then

@when("foo")
def foo(context):
    pass

@then("bar")
def bar(context):
    pass
```

`@when` and `@then` are automatically put into the files that Behave loads from the `steps/` subdirectories but not from any other module that you load with `import`.

I can then run it with fake feature files that call upon the steps defined in `common.py`:

```
$ behave Tests/BehaveTest*
Feature: BehaveTest1 # Tests/BehaveTest1/BehaveTest1.feature:1

  Scenario: foo  # Tests/BehaveTest1/BehaveTest1.feature:3
    When foo     # Tests/common.py:3 0.000s
    Then bar     # Tests/common.py:7 0.000s

Feature: BehaveTest2 # Tests/BehaveTest2/BehaveTest2.feature:1

  Scenario: foo  # Tests/BehaveTest2/BehaveTest2.feature:3
    When foo     # Tests/common.py:3 0.000s
    Then bar     # Tests/common.py:7 0.000s

2 features passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
4 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.000s
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this was the exact use case I was facing and this answer provided the clearest solution, with no dirty workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no other way like the way you are doing it:

You want to import code from some location. That means you need to make python aware of this location. And that is done via the PYTHONPATH or sys.path.append().

Behave is (as far as I know) only able to find code in the "steps" directory where the feature-file is located. If you have additional code, you have to set the sys.path.

In python > 3.3 it can be bit easier, since the "namespace" packages ([pep420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) makes it possible to call

```
 :$ behave Tests/BehaveTest1/BehaveTest1.feature
```

within the parent folder of your Tests directory. Then you would have to do

```
import Tests.common
```

within your step files.

That is because Tests, BehaveTests1 and BehaveTests2 would become a python package.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a structure like this, the steps from alice.features and bob.features will run if I run this command : "behave" or "behave --tags @"

```
DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:
+-- features/
     +-- steps/   (optional, common steps)
        +-- alice.features/
         |     +-- steps/   (specific steps for alice sub features, can use common steps)
         |     +-- *.feature
        +-- bob.features/
             +-- steps/
             +-- *.feature
      +-- environment.py
```